# Running Evernote 4 with Wine in Ubuntu

Tags: wine, evernote

I heard that we can now run Evernote with Wine. May I know what is the configuration to do so ?

Ubuntu version : 

Wine version :

Evernote Version :

Wine Configuration (Win XP, Win 7) :

Thank you.

Regards,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the procedure to install evernote 4 on ubuntu
http://www.webupd8.org/2010/10/you-can-finally-install-evernote-4-in.html

Here is the link on how to install evernote 3
http://abbysays.wordpress.com/2008/05/24/how-to-install-evernote-30-on-ubuntu/

[image]

Or you can install the alternative of evernote which is nevernote which works natively in Ubuntu.
Here is the link, If you want to know what is nevernote and how to install
http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/tag/nevernote/

Comment: Thank you for the tip. Will give this a try in my Ubuntu 10.04 box tonight =)